# Density function of a stationary processus

Tags: density-function, stationarity

I have a question: Let X be a wide-sense stationary processes. is a density function of X is almost periodic? why?

A continuous function $F:R \rightarrow L_2$ is said to be almost periodic, if for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $l>0$ such that any interval of length $l$ contains at least an $\epsilon$-almost period, that is number $\tau$ for which $sup_{t \in R}||F(t+\tau)-F(t)||_{L2}<\epsilon$, for all t in R .

Comment: Definition of almost periodic function :

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPeriodicFunction.html

Comment: Please do not repost your questions: edit the original.  Our [help] explains how this works.